# Rewrite html file for php with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help with converting html with php .

So far My code is

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ([a-z]+).html /$1.php
```

This is working fine. but some real html pages have php scripts ,that doesnt run. how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Need more clarification. What do you mean by **some real html pages have php scripts** and what URLs are not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler)
 directive to change the [mime type](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html)
 of a file

Add the following line to your htaccess file

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Now all your html files will work as php.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```